# Выполнение кода перед входом в интерактивный режим

Tags: lua

Как при открытии оболочки lua выполнить какой-либо код? В `bash`, к примеру, есть `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

из `man lua`:

> At  the very start, before even handling the command line, lua checks the contents of the environment variables LUA_INIT_5_2  or  LUA_INIT, in  that  order.   If  the  contents is of the form '@filename', then filename is executed.  Otherwise, the string is assumed to be  a  Lua statement and is executed.

мой вольный перевод:

> в самом начале, даже до обработки командной строки, lua проверяет содержимое переменной окружения LUA_INIT_5_2 (для версии 5.2) или LUA_INIT, в таком порядке. если содержимое имеет форму `@имя_файла`, то файл с таким именем выполняется. иначе строка рассматривается как выражение lua и выполняется.

---

так что в тот же `~/.bashrc` можно добавить что-нибудь вроде:

```
export LUA_INIT="@/путь/к/файлу"
```

и этот файл будет неким аналогом инициализационного файла.

---

правда, выполняться он будет не только при вызове интерактивного режима.

Comment: У меня в башрц сидит вот такая хрень: `export LUA_INIT="_PROMPT='\27[32m;\27[0m '_PROMPT2='\27[45m \27[0m '"`

Comment: А как узанать, интерактив или нет?

Comment: @val, вероятно, проанализировав аргументы.